# Superpose an image to a div in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following situation:

[image]

An image with a "tail".

Often the text is too long to fit the image, so I would like to leave the text flow away of the image (display the full text's length). In order to not see the white text on the white background, I need to make the div of same color like the image.

Have a look on the following **fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/ZtJc9/

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Item 1, Long description</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
</ul>

li {
    background: url(blueImageWithTail.jpg);
    height:(imageWITHOUTtailHeight)px;
    float:left;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

The question:

How to indicate in CSS that the image could "go out" of the div in the bottom ?

Comment: What are you wanting to happen? The text to be truncated to the width of the image, or the text to extend beyond the image?

Comment: This might not be the best solution but it should be what you are looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ZtJc9/1/

Comment: @serhio:i did not understand what you have asked.Could you comment here so that i can understand a lot better

Comment: "queue" = "tail". Please be sure to translate all of your thought process from French ;)

Comment: @Katstevens The text should be displayed in its full width! See the updated question...

Comment: @web-tiki thanks a lot! is was useful to use ::before, the position:absolute and relative combination, also the z-index!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you use css3 for it ? Here is an updated version of your fiddle.The color is not the same but i hope it helps you out. I used `::before` for to achieve this

http://jsfiddle.net/LaJFN/12/

Comment: Impressive use of CSS3! thanks! The only thing I am afraid it the compatibility with browsers that does not support CSS3 yet... however I saw multiple moz and webkit usage....

Comment: (in Firefox the "corner" displays with some "white" lines, but is not the case of Opera)
http://jsfiddle.net/LaJFN/14/